# React Router Undefined Routes Handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've noticed a strange behavior in react-router. 
I have my routes defined like so:

```
var routes = (
  <Route name='app' path='/' handler={Master}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={HomePage} />
    {/* inject:route */}
    <Route name='home' handler={HomePage} />
    <Route name='issues' handler={IssuesPage} />
    <Route name='security' handler={SecurityPage} />
    <Route name='contactUs' handler={ContactUsPage} />
    <Route name='docs' handler={DocsPage} />
    {/* endinject */}
    <Redirect from='/' to='/home' />
    <NotFoundRoute handler={HomePage}/>
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler />, document.body);
});
```

in our fork of https://github.com/shovon/generator-react-material-ui.

Clicking links in the LeftNav produces expected results.
Upon starting gulp, the redirect from / to /home works.
What seems weird and undesirable is when I type in something like `http://localhost:3000/#/some-undefined-route`. 
As expected, the DefaultRoute handler takes over, and the home page content is visible. HOWEVER, the weird URL remains. What I would expect is for any undefined route to redirect to a pre-defined catch-all. For example, I want `http://localhost:3000/#/some-undefined-route` to automatically redirect to `http://localhost:3000/#/home` -- not just show that content.

We're trying to use a mixin with `transitionTo()` to achieve the desired effect, but I'm still wondering if anybody knows the "right" way to handle this. I also wonder if what I'm seeing is actually the intended react-router behavior. If I'm missing something, I'd love to be enlightened. Cheers!

**Update**

From taurose at react-router:

> Have you tried
>
> `<Redirect from="*" to=".." />`

when responding to https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/732.

What might help anybody else with a similar question is to be aware that **you will have to provide a Redirect for each sub-route**, as well.

Apparently, this set up is designed to allow more detailed route control and handling of things like 404s.

Initially, we suspected that might be the case, but I didn't understand how the splat ( `from="*"` ) works.
Maybe this will be useful to others.
Cheers.